# Creating procedure to login with password hashed and salt, returning Incorrect password

Tags: sql-server

Ok, so I am making an ASP.net website application that has a registration form that will take in details about the user and the password will be encrypted with a registration procedure that will hash and salt the password. Now the problem is that when creating a login procedure. The login procedure that I implemented is displaying "Incorrect password" on `@responseMessage` output when passing in the username and password. What could be the problem and how to fix this issue?

**RestuarantProc** - Registration Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RestuarantProc]
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
    @LastName NVARCHAR(50),
    @UserName NVARCHAR(50),
    @Password NVARCHAR(50),
    @Age INT,
    @Email VARCHAR(100),
    @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250) OUTPUT
AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()
            BEGIN TRY
                INSERT INTO RestuarantReg(FirstName, LastName, UserName, PasswordHash, PasswordSalt, Age, Email)
                VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @UserName, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password+CAST(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36))), 
                @salt, @Age, @Email)

                SET @responseMessage='Success'
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                SET @responseMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE()
            END CATCH
    END
GO

DECLARE @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)

EXEC dbo.RestuarantProc @FirstName = 'Bob', @LastName = 'Hudgins', @UserName = 'bobh123', @Password = 'password', 
@Age = '23', @Email = 'bob@bob.com', @responseMessage = @responseMessage OUTPUT

SELECT * FROM RestuarantReg
```

**RestuarantProcLogin** - Login Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RestuarantProcLogin
    @userName NVARCHAR(254),
    @password NVARCHAR(50),
    @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)='' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @userID INT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [dbo].[RestuarantReg] WHERE UserName=@userName)
    BEGIN
        SET @userID=(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[RestuarantReg] 
        WHERE UserName=@userName AND 
        PasswordHash=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @password+CAST(PasswordSalt AS NVARCHAR(36))))

        IF(@userID IS NULL)
            SET @responseMessage='Incorrect password'
        ELSE
            SET @responseMessage='User successfully logged in'
    END
    ELSE
        SET @responseMessage='Invalid login'
END

DECLARE @responseMessage nvarchar(250)

EXEC dbo.RestuarantProcLogin @userName = N'bobh123', @password = N'password', @responseMessage = @responseMessage OUTPUT
SELECT @responseMessage as N'@responseMessage'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your `RestuarantReg` table definition.

Comment: Don't pass the password to the RDBMS at all; people can (and will) intercept those passwords! Use the username to retrieve the salt and hash, and then use that salt to hash the password in the application. If the values match, you have the right value.

Comment: I posted `RestuarantReg` table

Comment: @Larnu Basically what you are saying is, that I should generate salt and hash in visual studio only and anything passed to the database, in my case SQL server, should only be received as PasswordHash and PasswordSalt?

Comment: Generate the value in the application and pass only the already salted hashed value.

Comment: Basically, what you are saying is, there is nothing wrong with the SQL Procedure at all.

Comment: That isn't what @DanGuzman is saying at all. Your passing a plain text password to SQL Server; you should never do that. Dan is saying use the Username to receive the Salt for the Password. Then use the Salt to Hash the Password and then pass the salted and hashed password to the RDBMS and check it exists against the username. Considering the password (even the hashed one) isn't exposed that's the most secure.

Comment: @AlejandroH, Larnu correctly expanded on my comment. The best practice is for the application to 1) take the clear password (hopefully, encrypted over the wire) and add the salt, 2) calculate the salted hash value, and 3) store it in the database. To verify the password later, same steps 1 and 2 and pass the salted hash value to the database for comparison with the previously stored value.

Comment: I successfully created a PasswordHash class that hashes the password and I am now passing the hashed password into the sql server. Also, I removed `PasswordHash=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @password+CAST(PasswordSalt AS NVARCHAR(36)))` as I am already hashing it in c#. I tested the values in sql server and login was successful. Now I just have to figure out a way to display success or not in the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Move the calculation of the hash into a function. Easy to do, easy to maintain, single point of definition. Problem solved if you keep the datastore for your vars the same as your table.